# Why does using Requests fail when the URL works fine in browser?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have this code that used to work but I now get connection timeout errors when I run it. I assumed that something changed on the URL but when I paste the URL into a browser I get a successful response. Yet when curling from Terminal or running it in Pycharm I get the timeout error.

I have tried setting headers and retries but still can't get a successful response when using Requests.

```
import requests

# Creating a session object
session = requests.Session()

# Add headers with your user-agent
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.3 Safari/605.1.15'
}

# Making a POST request using the session
response = session.post('https://www.valueinvestorsclub.com/ideas/loadideas', headers=headers)

# Print the response
print(response)
```

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.valueinvestorsclub.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ideas/loadideas (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x122309b80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'))
```

Comment: Pasting the address into a browser is a GET request.  So why is your code using a POST request?

Answer (score 0):

You can try inspecting the network when doing the request in the browser and then copy the curl request and transform it into python using this site

https://curlconverter.com/

This way you can figure out what might be missing here, maybe cookies are not up to date, maybe it requires a login, hard to know without playing a little bit

Edit: also as John stated, if you want to retrieve data, the HTTP verb is GET

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you should use `.get` instead of `.post`.

Also, the returned data is in Json format, so you can use `.json()` method to parse it. Custom headers aren't required:

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.valueinvestorsclub.com/ideas/loadideas"

data = requests.get(url).json()
print(data)
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "result": {
        "Wednesday, Dec 13, 2023": [
            {
                "id": 155354,
                "keyid": "5365271522",
                "company_name": "ROIVANT SCIENCES LTD",
                "symbol": "ROIV",
                "add_date": "2023-12-13 08:19:39",
                "format_date": "Wednesday, Dec 13, 2023",
                "total_return": None,
                "deleted_by_user_id": None,


...
```

Comment: @user53526356 Are you using some proxy? Perhaps you're running the code from remote server? It could be the IP address of the computer from where you're running the code is banned by the server.